# Не обрабатывается исключение

Tags: c++, исключения

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
void func(int a)
{
    if (a == 0)
        throw "Error: Null argument";
}
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    try
    {
        func(a);
    }
    catch (exception& err)
    {
        cout <<"Standart exception: " << err.what() << endl;
    }
    cout << "The end:";
    return 0;
}
```

Здравствуйте, не обрабатывается исключение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы обработать исключение, надо верно указать его тип:

```
try
{
    func(a);
}
catch(char const * const err)
{
    cout <<"Non-Standart exception: " << err << endl;
}
catch (exception const & err)
{
    cout <<"Standart exception: " << err.what() << endl;
}
```

Можно также бросать исключение, производное от `exception`, например,

```
void func(int a)
{
    if (a == 0)
        throw runtime_error("Error: Null argument");
}
```

Comment: @user7860670 А чем так принципиальны `const`? Работает и так, как я написал.

Comment: Если сначала объявить, что переменная будет изменяться, а затем ее не изменять, то получится как в том анекдоте - "Я кондуктора обманул: взял билет и не поехал".

Comment: @user7860670 И что? Откуда мне знать, что именно в обработчике напишет ТС? Вдруг он намерен его менять?

Comment: Что он напишет - не важно, важно то, что фактически написано в ответе.